# What is the safe way to scan external drive for viruses

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, anti-virus

I have an external drive which contains lots of important files and MacOS time machine backup. I had to plug it to a computer in our school and my drive is infected by viruses.

Now I'm worrying about plugging it to my Macbook. I don't know if this virus can affect OS X . And I don't want macbook to infected. So what is the safest way to clean my disk WITHOUT DATA LOSE .

Comment: Use something life a LiveCD that can read HFS and copy your known clean files/backups off. If there are no programs running that are likely to "revive" or "feed" the virus then it can't cause any damage or infect other devices. You should also ensure you have more than one backup of your important data. There is no excuse for no or less than 2 backups anymore.

Comment: What makes you think its infected?

Comment: @BigChris But I don't know which files are *clean* ?

Comment: @Ramhound , when I plug it in PC at my school, suddenly my all files disappeared (they marked as *hidden file*) and new files appeared with same file names .

Comment: Your school uses OS X if not then it's not infected

Comment: No it's not OS X .It's Windows.

Comment: I see, home = Mac, school = PC. Don't worry. A Windows virus won't infect a Mac because the two OS architectures are wildly different.

Comment: Sounds like the Windows machine where you plugged in your USB drive had the [hidden folder virus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hfv/)